# Advertise with `ServiceDiscovery.Dnssd`, discover with Bonjour?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, bonjour, dns-sd

Does the [`Windows.Networking.ServiceDiscovery.Dnssd` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.servicediscovery.dnssd) allow advertising a service that is discoverable through Apple's Bonjour?

Microsoft's documentation mentions all the right DNS-SD RFCs, but I can't discover my program using this [Bonjour Browser program](https://hobbyistsoftware.com/bonjourbrowser). I know that the Bonjour Browser program is working because it discovers other devices on my network as well as local services advertised through `mDNSResponder`. And Microsoft's documentation on this namespace is sufficiently vague to leave me wondering.

Does anything obviously wrong stand out in this code?

```
async Task RegisterServiceAsync()
{
    var hostNames = NetworkInformation
        .GetHostNames()
        .Where(x => x.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, HostName>(x.ToString(), x))
        .ToList();
    var hostName = Pick("Pick a host name:", hostNames);
    Console.WriteLine($"Host name is \"{hostName}\"");

    var service = new DnssdServiceInstance(
        dnssdServiceInstanceName: "abc._tcp.local.",
        hostName: hostName,
        port: 13337
    );
    using (var socket = new StreamSocketListener())
    {
        var registration = await service.RegisterStreamSocketListenerAsync(socket);
        Console.WriteLine(registration.Status);
        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed: {registration.HasInstanceNameChanged}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Service instance name: {service.DnssdServiceInstanceName}");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
        1) hostname.domain.local
        2) hostname.local
Pick a host name: (1-2) 2
Host name is "hostname.local"
Success
Renamed: False
Service instance name: abc._tcp.local.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dnssdServiceInstanceName` was in the wrong format. It needs to be `<<instance name>>._<<service name>>._<<protocol>>.<<domain>>.`. For example, this code works:

```
async Task RegisterServiceAsync()
{
    var hostNames = NetworkInformation
        .GetHostNames()
        .Where(x => x.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, HostName>(x.ToString(), x))
        .ToList();
    var hostName = Pick("Pick a host name:", hostNames);
    Console.WriteLine($"Host name is \"{hostName}\"");

    var service = new DnssdServiceInstance(
        dnssdServiceInstanceName: "instanceName._abcservice._tcp.local.",
        hostName: hostName,
        port: 13337
    );
    using (var socket = new StreamSocketListener())
    {
        var registration = await service.RegisterStreamSocketListenerAsync(socket);
        Console.WriteLine(registration.Status);
        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed: {registration.HasInstanceNameChanged}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Service instance name: {service.DnssdServiceInstanceName}");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

I figured this out using [this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-networkhelper/blob/7ac7f7a04cd4143302c9bb86fd482e633e6fd882/NetworkHelper/DnssdManager.cs#L100) of a Microsoft example program.